# Nginx with Nuxt not serving the domain

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am new to Nginx and have been trying to set up server blocks in Nginx, locally on macOS. The purpose is to render Nuxt app when a user requests a certain domain. However, even after spending hours and hours on it, I am not able to identify why I can not hit the domain (here example1256.com) and get the nuxt app content in return.
[This is my nginx.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ5M4.png)
[etc/hosts (which btw I created myself, hosts file was not there from installation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uR2N.png)
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HXLX.png)

If I try doing 127.0.0.1:8080, I get the Nuxt content in return. However, hitting the domain always yeilds this:[browser: chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxMTQ.png)

Comment: Did you do this `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` after saving your changes in the `hosts` file? What happens if you try to `ping example1256.com` from your terminal?

Comment: I figured out this. Basically the hosts file I was accessing was not correct. Mac hides files at times so the correct hosts file was hidden. I found it out and configured my domains and it started working!